# httpie TLS version error

Tags: ssl, httpie

On Mac, I'm using `httpie` for testing REST API. After enabling HTTPs on my server, which only supports TLS 1.2, I started to have the following error:

```
http: error: SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590)
```

If I'm to guess, I'd say `httpie` is trying to use an older version of TLS. Anybody seen this one before? How to resolve it?

On my PC running Ubuntu MATE, it works without hassle.

Comment: It sounds like this issue: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1847

Comment: Yes but it didn't end in a good solution. :(

Comment: most of the time the issue is the ssl verison, I'd start by comparing the output of `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION`